# update dojo datagrid

Tags: ajax, datagrid, dojo

I need to display a data grid in my website. When user logs into website, an ajax request is send to get whole data for the grid. After that cell updates will come(json response) from dojo ajax requests to server. So how to update those cells only in data grid automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To update items in the datagrid store :

```
grid.store.fetch({query:{/*find items to update*/},
  onItem : function(gridItem){
     grid.store.setValue(gridItem, attr, value);
});
grid.store.save();
```

Setting the attributes you want to update to the appropriate value from the xhr response.